# Size of a char in a byte array

Tags: java, string, casting, arrays

As [java doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) states it:

> char: The char data type is a single 16-bit Unicode character. It has a minimum value of '\u0000' (or 0) and a maximum value of '\uffff' (or 65,535 inclusive).

But when I have a String (just containing ASCII-signs) and convert it to a byte array, every sign of the String is stored in one byte, which is less than the 16 bit as java docs states it. How does it work? I could imagine that the java compiler/interpreter uses just one byte per char for an ASCII sign for performance issues.

Furthermore, what happens if I've got a String with just ASCII signs and one UTF-16 sign and convert it to a byte array. Every sign of the String uses 2 bytes now?

Comment: How did you "convert" it?

Comment: What is an ASCII "sign"?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2164804/from-compilation-to-runtime-how-does-java-string-encoding-really-work

Comment: @keshlam: Sorry, I forgot to tell you how to convert: `byte[] bytes = string.getBytes();` . Explicitly without giving a charset.
@Elliott Frisch: I don't get you counterquestion. [Here's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) a link to ASCII.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Converting characters to bytes and vice versa is done using a [character encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding).

The character encoding determines how characters are represented by bytes. For example, [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) is a character encoding which uses 7 bits per character. Obviously, it can only represent 128 characters, way less than the 65,536 characters that exist in Java.

Other character encodings are UTF-8 and UTF-16. In fact, a Java `char` is really an UTF-16 character - if you directly cast it to an `int`, you would get the UTF-16 code for the character.

Here's a longer tutorial to character encodings: [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/).

If you call `getBytes()` on a `String`, it will use the default character encoding of the system to convert the characters in the string to bytes. It's better to use the version of `getBytes()` that takes a character set name as an argument, so that you know what character set is used. For example:

```
byte[] bytes = str.getBytes("UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 2):

The internal format of a String uses 16 bits per character. When you convert it to a byte array, you use a certain character encoding which is either specified explicitly or the default platform encoding. The encoding may use fewer bits per character.

For example the ASCII encoding will store each character in a byte but it can only represent 128 different characters.

Another often used encoding is UTF-8 which uses a variable number of bytes per character. The first 128 characters (corresponding to the characters available in ASCII) can be stored in one byte each. Characters with order numbers 128 or higher need two or more bytes.

Comment: but the question has a point: what if the string has many different characters (more than 256 different characters), and you convert them to byte array, will it still be of the size of the string? if so, how could you convert them back , as each byte holds only up to 256 characters... i hope it means that the bytes array length will be double the number of characters of the string.

Comment: @androiddeveloper no, UTF-8 is a variable length encoding. If the highest bit in the byte is 0, it is a one byte character, if the highest bit is 1 the character is represented in more than one byte. There is no easy way to get the length of the string from the length of the byte array. You need to look at each byte.

Comment: but that's what i've written - you would probably get double the bytes count, no? or only for some of the characters? question is, how do you convert to a string back. never tried it before.

Comment: @androiddeveloper more than one byte is used only for some of the characters. The standard methods to convert back do the right thing.

Comment: I see. thank you. i guess the conversion back is "new String(bytes, "UTF-8");" .

Answer (score 1):

`getBytes() 
Encodes this String into a sequence of bytes using the platform's default charset, storing the result into a new byte array.`

Your platform's default charset is probably UTF8. Hence, getBytes() will use one byte per character for characters which fit comfortably into that size.

Answer (score 1):

`String.getBytes()` "encodes this String into a sequence of bytes using the platform's default charset, storing the result into a new byte array". The platform's default charset (`Charset.defaultCharset()`) is probably UTF-8.

As for the second question, strings aren't actually required to use UTF-16. The way a JVM stores strings internally is irrelevant. The few occurrences of `UTF-16` in the JVM spec apply only to `char`s.