# How Character to byte encoding is handled at runtime in java?

Tags: java, arrays, sockets

I have a nio client server implementation from client side I am sending an character with ascii value 40981 which looks like 'ꀕ' this character is casted in to integer and sent over as a byte array to server, Server library is already compiled by a third party and when it is reading the bytes to server it is reading the it as a character with ascii value 21577. This problem started happening when we have upgraded the runtime JVM to 1.8.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2164804/from-compilation-to-runtime-how-does-java-string-encoding-really-work See if this is helpful

Comment: Can't say much without the actual code - and the server's code as well. If it's a known library, a reference to it would help. And which JVM did you use before?

Comment: There is no such thing as "ascii" values 40981 or 21577  They are *way* outside the ASCII range (0-127). Decimal 40981 is Unicode codepoint `U+A015` (`ꀕ`), and 21577 is `U+5449` (`呉`). As you can see, those values are *nothing alike*. It is not likely that you could be sending the value in one encoding and reading it another encoding to get this result, either. The only way I can see that sending 40981 but receiving 21577 would happen is if your communications is just completely corrupted to begin with.  What does the actual protocol look like between client and server?

Comment: Why are you *casting* a character to an integer at all?  Please show your actual code.  It makes more sense to put the character in a `String` and use `String.getBytes()` to charset-encode the string to a byte array.