# Why Windows console code page influences the compilation and running of a Java program with ANSI characters?

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, decoding, codepages

According to [From compilation to runtime, how does Java String encoding really work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2164804/from-compilation-to-runtime-how-does-java-string-encoding-really-work), Strings in Java class file are independent of the code page in use. But I found the following problem in a Java program in a GBK(ANSI encoding used in China) machine.
Suppose the following characters:

AString

ANSIStringAsUTF is what AString looks like when it's encoded with ANSI and decoded with UTF-8.

UTFStringAsANSI is what AString looks like when it's encoded with UTF-8 and decoded with ANSI.

So when I enter AString in notepad++ with ANSI, save the file and open the file with ANSI, it looks right. If I open the file with UTF-8, it shows ANSIStringAsUTF.
when I enter AString in notepad++ with UTF-8, save the file and open the file with UTF-8, it looks right. If I open the file with ANSI, it shows UTFStringAsANSI. Fine!

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(*AString*);
    }
}
```

I compile the java file above encoded in UTF-8 in a Windows console with ANSI code page 936, run it. It looks as expected.
I change the code page to 65001(UTF-8) with chcp command and run it, it shows ANSIStringAsUTF.

I compile the java file above encoded in UTF-8 in a Windows console with UTF-8 code page, run it. It looks as expected.
I change the code page to 936 with chcp command and run it, it shows UTFStringAsANSI.

The behavior is identical to editing file with notepad++, i.e. the code page in use decides the encoding and decoding of Strings in Java. Could anyone tell me why? Sorry for the verbose question.

Comment: "the code page in use decides the encoding and decoding of Strings in Java" - I don't think you've shown that. You've shown that it affects how strings are *displayed on the console*. I suggest you separate out the two ideas of "the string as it exists in memory" and "the result of calling System.out.println". Ideally, change your code to dump the UTF-16 code units (as integers) as well as the string as text. That way you can tell the difference easily.

Comment: Java strings are independent of the encoding. But source code is not. And the console is not. And reading  and writing text files is not. For all of them, the involved encoding needs to be understood and controlled. Many people encounter an encoding issue and add *print* statements, introducing even more encoding issues instead of solving the problem. Do you want to improve your understanding of encoding or do you have a specific problem to be solved?

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I do understand the difference between the encoding of String and source code etc. But 1. The fact the program prints correctly some way indicates AString is decoded right during compilation in both cases. 2. The fact that the program prints incorrectly some way shows Java doesn't encode the output string according to the code page in use correctly. 3. The fact that the two cases differ shows the code page in use influence the compiled class. 4. To make it worse, the result varies and some time I found UTFStringAsANSI in both compiled class when opened with UTF-8.

Comment: @StarrowPan: #1 doesn't necessarily follow. It's possible that a string is handled wrong twice and shows correctly in the output. It depends on the specific combinations of errors if that's possible, but it's not unheard of. And #4 clearly demonstrates that there is some problem with your methodology. I suggest you put your findings into a very small script that automatically demonstrates the problem (should only be one batch/powershell file and one Java source file). In other words: produce a [mre].

Comment: Oh, and last but not least: if you're convinced that despite `-encoding UTF-8` the system encoding influence the **compilation** of Java classes with `javac` then this should be even simpler to demonstrate with a tiny script using just `javac` and `javap`.

Answer (score 1):

The [`javac`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/specs/man/javac.html) command has an option for specifying encoding:

> `-encoding encoding`
> Specifies character encoding used by source files, such as EUC-JP and UTF-8. **If the `-encoding` option is not specified, then the platform default converter is used.**

Since you're not specifying the option, the code page of the command prompt is used to determine the platform default encoding.

It is common good practice to always save Java source files in UTF-8, and to explicitly specify `-encoding UTF-8` when compiling manually, so the compilation is unaffected by the environment settings.

It is even more common practice to not compile manually, but use a build tool such as Maven, Gradle, or Ant, and specify the ending option in the build script. That way you never have to think about it again.

It is highly recommended to use an IDE, instead of a text editor like Notepad++, and to configure the IDE to always use UTF-8.

Comment: Thank you. I understand the option and follow the practices. I encounter the problem and try to find the reason by doing all the things manually. The source is encoded in UTF-8 and compiled with & without the -encoding UTF-8 option, the results don't change.